# reformat long range of data in google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula

I have rows of data with columns like example below:
[Current Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL6lT.jpg)

I want to pull the data in another sheet as follows:[Desire Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ERI.png)

I tried a combination of query,split and transpose but am not getting the result I want. Is this possible at all?

Link of spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1ct7HLdvgkY0tYaiUyduhehyci7Dt7p_ajNCKcJandS0/htmlview

Comment: Please share a copyable sample of your sheet so that we dont have to create one, and do share what you tried with more detail. See [how-ta-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Yes, it can be done with one formula. However, as noted above, please provide a link to an editable sheet containing exactly what is shown in your first image, being sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." This will be the most efficient way for those here to help you.

Comment: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ct7HLdvgkY0tYaiUyduhehyci7Dt7p_ajNCKcJandS0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two sheets ("Sheet1B" and "Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet.

'Sheet1B' is just a cleaned-up version of your 'Sheet1'. This sheet reflects the real-world layout. As such, my formula in 'Erik Help' references 'Sheet1B' ***and not*** 'Sheet1."

There is one formula in 'Erik Help'!A1:

`=ArrayFormula({Sheet1B!A1:J1; QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1B!A2:A & "|" & Sheet1B!B2:B & "|" & Sheet1B!C2:C & "|" & Sheet1B!D2:D,",","~") & REPT(",|||",LEN(Sheet1B!E2:E)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1B!E2:E,",",""))),",",1,0),"~",",") & "|" & SPLIT(Sheet1B!E2:E,",") & "|" & SPLIT(Sheet1B!F2:F,",") & "|" & SPLIT(Sheet1B!G2:G,",") & "|" & SPLIT(Sheet1B!H2:H,",") & "|" & SPLIT(Sheet1B!I2:I,",") & "|" & SPLIT(REPT(",",LEN(Sheet1B!E2:E)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1B!E2:E,",",""))) & Sheet1B!J2:J,",",1,0),Sheet1B!A2:A<>"")),"|",1,0),"Select * WHERE Col5 Is Not Null")})`

This one formula produces all headers and results seen and will expand to include new rows of data.

As you can see, I strongly recommend placing the formula in its own sheet, rather than in the same sheet as the raw data. However, if you must place it in the same sheet as the raw data, do not place it *below* the raw data, since this would inhibit the ability of the raw data range to grow naturally. Place it to the right. In that case, given the current layout of your 'Sheet1' (and assuming you delete all data from Row 7 down, the formula would look like this:

`=ArrayFormula({A3:J3; QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A4:A & "|" & B4:B & "|" & C4:C & "|" & D4:D,",","~") & REPT(",|||",LEN(E4:E)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E4:E,",",""))),",",1,0),"~",",") & "|" & SPLIT(E4:E,",") & "|" & SPLIT(F4:F,",") & "|" & SPLIT(G4:G,",") & "|" & SPLIT(H4:H,",") & "|" & SPLIT(I4:I,",") & "|" & SPLIT(REPT(",",LEN(E4:E)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E4:E,",",""))) & J4:J,",",1,0),A4:A<>"")),"|",1,0),"Select * WHERE Col5 Is Not Null")})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in row 4 as per my screengrab below:

`=arrayformula(query(iferror(array_constrain({vlookup({flatten(split(row(E4:E)&rept(","&0,len(H4:H)-len(regexreplace(H4:H,",",""))),","))},{row(E4:E),A4:D},{2,3,4,5},false),flatten(split(E4:E,",")),flatten(split(F4:F,",")),flatten(split(G4:G,",")),flatten(split(H4:H,",")),flatten(split(I4:I,",")),vlookup({flatten(split(rept(0&",",len(H4:H)-len(regexreplace(H4:H,",","")))&row(E4:E),","))},{row(E4:E),E4:J},7,false)},max(if(F4:F<>"",len(F4:F)-len(regexreplace(F4:F,",",""))+1,))*counta(F4:F),10),),"where Col6 is not null",0))`

[image]

It's made up of 3 sections:

The first 4 cols:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup({flatten(split(row(E4:E)&rept(","&0,len(H4:H)-len(regexreplace(H4:H,",",""))),","))},{row(E4:E),A4:D},{2,3,4,5},false),))`

The middle 5 columns:

`=arrayformula(array_constrain({flatten(split(E4:E,",")),flatten(split(F4:F,",")),flatten(split(G4:G,",")),flatten(split(H4:H,",")),flatten(split(I4:I,","))},max(if(F4:F<>"",len(F4:F)-len(regexreplace(F4:F,",",""))+1,))*counta(F4:F),6))`

The end grand total column:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup({flatten(split(rept(0&",",len(H4:H)-len(regexreplace(H4:H,",","")))&row(E4:E),","))},{row(E4:E),E4:J},7,false),))`

Assumptions:

When you have comma-separated items in columns E,F,G,H,I you have the same quantity in cells on the same row. The quantity can differ on a different row. The example shows rows 4 to 7 as 3,2,3,4 items.

Your GrandTotal figure is already worked out.

If this helps, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :-)